# Recuperar valor de un Array en diferentes métodos del mismo modulo VB6

Tags: vb6

Tengo un array el cual lleno en el formulario1 y lo envío al formulario2 al metodo Frm2.LlenarVales(array()), hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando quiero usar el array en el método grabar parece que el array esta vacío y manda el error "valor fuera del intervalo".

Formulario 1

```html
Frm2.LlenarVales(array())
```

Formulario 2

```html
Dim array() as Integer
Dim I As Long

Public Function Grabar()    

    For I = 1 To UBound(array)
        MsgBox "Valor: " & (array(I)), vbInformation, "Mensaje"
    Next
    
End Function

Public Function LlenarVales(array() As Integer) 
    array() = array()
                 
    For I = 1 To UBound(array)
        MsgBox "Valor: " & (array(I)), vbInformation, "Mensaje"
    Next
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes que usar UBound de la siguiente forma:

```
Ubound(arrData)
```

Si esto devuelve mayor o igual a cero, quiere decir que el array tiene datos.

Igual, es raro que no sepas con anticipacion cuantos datos contiene el array. Como tu array tiene un tamaño fijo (en vb6), entonces deberias tener un puntero al ultimo elemento ingresado para saber hasta donde llegaste.

Comment: Hola me marca el error 'el subíndice esta fuera del intérvalo'. El array es dinamico por eso lo he declarado asi: Dim arrData() As Integer, el tamaño es variable

Comment: @Huntzberger ahi lo edite.. fijate si asi te funciona.. hace mucho que no trabajo con esto... capaz le estoy pifiando en ese caso buscaremos otro que se acuerde mas que yo... igual, podrias probar acceder a una posicion y agarrar el error con un on error en el peor de los casos